# Does the Venture actually exist?

Tags: wing-commander

In Wing Commander 1, the [Claw Marks (PDF)](http://download.wcnews.com/files/manuals/Wing%20Commander%20-%20Claw%20Marks.pdf) (the official manual, written in-character) mentions a Terran corvette class called [Venture](http://www.wcnews.com/wcpedia/index.php?title=Venture-Class_Corvette). In the years I've played WC1, I have never encountered one in a single mission and it has thus become a great mystery to me and the people I played it with, whether the Venture actually exists in the game. Was it just a myth? Scrapped before release?

Has anyone seen one and if so, in which mission? I guess the task was to defend it?

[Here](http://www.wcnews.com/wcpedia/Category:Wing_Commander_missions) is a mission tree of WC1 in case you want to refer to a mission specifically.

Comment: This has made me nostalgic for those old WC manuals.  As a kid I think I might've spent more time looking at those ship designs than actually playing the game.

Comment: From a time when manuals were still part of the art that made up the game (together with the box), and not a lame Wordpad file typed down, then put on the disk in the DVD mini-box. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only played WC on the SNES, and it's been forever since I've played it, but in searching for "Venture" in the [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/588851-wing-commander/faqs/9829) on GameFAQS.com it does mention the word once as part of the secret missions (no idea why they are secret).

From the FAQ (emphasis mine):

> 7.2.1     Goddard 1
>         Defend, strike, escort, sweep... What don’t you do in this mission?
>
> N01 has 4 Salthi and a Lumbari.
>   Asteroids with 2 Salthi are at N12. At
>   N2 you need to protect the Diligent
>   from 3 Krants. When you reach N3, **the
>   Venture-class corvette** is under attack
>   by 3 Krants. As you escort it to the
>   Claw 3 Salthis attack.
>
> At N12, try to lure the Salthis out of
>   the asteroid field to fight them. Save
>   the missiles for the fight at N2, as
>   the Diligent is more fragile than the
>   corvette.

Take this with as much salt as you like.

Comment: The CIC [seems to agree with you](http://www.wcnews.com/wcpedia/Alpha_Wing_%28Goddard_System%29) ( [mission tree](http://www.wcnews.com/wcpedia/Category:The_Secret_Missions_1:_Operation_Thor%27s_Hammer_missions) ). It's apparently even the first mission of SM1 (and I've played them at least one, so I'm surprised I don't remember the Venture, will have to play them again). Still doesn't really answer the question why it was in the Claw Marks. Does it really not appear in WC1? Then why was it mentioned there? Did they design the Claw Marks with the Secret Missions already in mind?

Comment: sorry, i'm no help with any of the rest of those :)